# Custom S4 Class in data.frame/tibble/data.table

Tags: r, r-s4

I am looking to use an S4 class, defined by me, inside of `data.frame`s (and/or tibbles, data.tables, ...), similar to what `lubridate::period()` offers.

E.g., the following code creates a vector of periods, stores them in a data.frame (tibble in this case), extracts one value and accesses the class again...

```r
tibble::tibble(
  x = c(lubridate::period(120), 
        lubridate::period(2))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   x       
#>   <Period>
#> 1 120S    
#> 2 2S 

str(
  tibble::tibble(
    x = c(lubridate::period(120), 
          lubridate::period(2))
  )$x[1]
)
#> Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
#>   ..@ .Data : num 120
#>   ..@ year  : num 0
#>   ..@ month : num 0
#>   ..@ day   : num 0
#>   ..@ hour  : num 0
#>   ..@ minute: num 0
```

I would like to replicate this with the typical `Person` class.

A first (failed) try looks like this:

```r
.person <- setClass("Person", 
                   slots = list(name = "character",
                                age = "numeric"))
person <- function(name, age) {
  .person(name = name, age = age)
}

format.Person <- function(x, ...) {
  paste0("<Person: ", x@name, " ", x@age, ">")
}


# create some instances
person("Alice", 123)
#> An object of class "Person"
#> Slot "name":
#>   [1] "Alice"
#> 
#> Slot "age":
#>   [1] 123

## Fair enough, no proper "show" method implemented yet...

format(person("Alice", 123))
#> [1] "<Person: Alice 123>"


ppl <- c(person("Alice", 123),
  person("Bob", 42))
ppl
#> [[1]]
#> An object of class "Person"
#> Slot "name":
#>   [1] "Alice"
#> 
#> Slot "age":
#>   [1] 123
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> An object of class "Person"
#> Slot "name":
#>   [1] "Bob"
#> 
#> Slot "age":
#>   [1] 42

## Now converting to data.frames

data.frame(x = ppl)
#> Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
#>   unique() applies only to vectors

tibble::tibble(x = ppl)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#> x       
#> <list>  
#>   1 <Person>
#>   2 <Person>

data.table::data.table(x = ppl)
#> x
#> 1: <Person[2]>
#> 2: <Person[2]>
```

What I want in the end is to have something along the lines of this:

```r
tibble::tibble(x = ppl)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   x     
#>   <Person>
#> 1 <Alice, 123>    
#> 2 <Bob, 42>
#>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this hasn't worked is because `data.frame`s (and similar objects like `tibble`s) can only contain *atomic* types in their columns (i.e. something that could be created from a call to `vector`). The atomic types are "logical", "integer", "double", "complex", "character", "raw" and "list".

In practice, that means your class will have to contain one of these atomic types (probably "list"), along the lines of `setClass("onePerson",contains="list")`. Having each slot be an atomic type is not enough on its own. If you want to enforce that the list has the correct components of the correct classes, then you can use `validObject` methods to enforce that.

It might be possible to stick with the class definition that you have that does not extend an atomic type, but you will need to write methods for functions like `cbind2` and `[` to allow it to interact with data frames.

Lastly, you could make your `person` class extend `data.frame` or `tibble` itself, with restrictions on the column names and types. This is essentially the same as the list solution, since a data frame *is* a list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint of @JDL regarding the atomic types and looking back at the `lubridate::period` definition, I found this solution.

The key is (besides `contains = "character"`) to have a slot named `.Data`

```r
.person <- setClass("Person", 
                    contains = "character",
                    slots = list(.Data = "character",
                                 name = "character",
                                 age = "numeric"))
person <- function(name, age) {
  .person(.Data = name, name = name, age = age)
}
setMethod("length", "Person", function(x) {
  length(x@.Data)
})
setMethod("show", "Person", function(object) {
  print(format(object))
})
setMethod("c", "Person", function(x, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  nempty <- sapply(dots, length) != 0
  elements <- dots[nempty]#lapply(dots[nempty], as.Person)

  .Data <- c(x@.Data, unlist(lapply(elements, slot, ".Data")))
  name <- c(x@name, unlist(lapply(elements, slot, "name")))
  age <- c(x@age, unlist(lapply(elements, slot, "age")))
  new("Person", .Data = .Data, name = name, age = age)
})
# apparently not strictly needed here
# setMethod("cbind2", "Person", function(x, y, ...) {
#   c(x, y, ...)
# })
setMethod("[", "Person", function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) {
  new("Person", .Data = x@.Data[i], name = x@name[i], age = x@age[i])
})

format.Person <- function(x, ...) {
  if (length(x) == 0) {
    return("<PERSON>")
  }
  
  paste0("<Person: ", x@name, " ", x@age, ">")
}

x <- person("Alice", 123)
x
#> [1] "<Person: Alice 123>"

format(person("Alice", 123))
#> [1] "<Person: Alice 123>"
c(x, x)
#> [1] "<Person: Alice 123>" "<Person: Alice 123>"

ppl <- c(person("Alice", 123),
         person("Bob", 42))
ppl
#> [1] "<Person: Alice 123>" "<Person: Bob 42>"
str(ppl)
#> Formal class 'Person' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
#>   ..@ .Data: chr [1:2] "Alice" "Bob"
#>   ..@ name : chr [1:2] "Alice" "Bob"
#>   ..@ age  : num [1:2] 123 42

data.frame(x = ppl)
#>       x
#> 1 Alice
#> 2   Bob
a <- tibble::tibble(x = ppl)
a
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   x       
#>   <Person>
#> 1 Alice   
#> 2 Bob    

str(a$x[1])
#> Formal class 'Person' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
#>   ..@ .Data: chr "Alice"
#>   ..@ name : chr "Alice"
#>   ..@ age  : num 123
data.table::data.table(x = ppl)
#>                      x
#> 1: <Person: Alice 123>
#> 2:    <Person: Bob 42>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: you don't actually need to initialise the slot "@.Data" — it is created automatically when you inherit from an atomic type