# Convert a list of "featvec" class objects (S4) to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, r-s4

I am trying to work with the "rcdk" R package. I use the get.fingerprint function, type='substructure', fp.mode='count', substructure.pattern=smarts. I get an object of "featvec" class (which is an S4 class object), which in theory could be processed with the "fingerprint" r package. However, I cannot find any function in the fingerprint package to deal with this type of object. I am interested in converting the counts of this object to a dataframe. I am stuck because I have a list of such S4 objects, which seem to be S4 objects of lists of S4 objects. I apologize for this sounding too complicated, for me it is too complicated, although for others probably the issue might be very simple. I attempted the use of unlist, as.data.frame, various for loops (but probably would need three or four levels) but managed to get various errors or other results than what I would have liked.
I provide this simple example, where I would like to get a data frame with 5 columns and 6 rows, formed by rbind-ing the features of each list element.:

```
moli <- c("c1nccc(c1)c1nc([nH]c1c1ccc(F)cc1)c1ccc(cc1)S(=O)C", "OC(=O)C[C@H](O)CC(O)COc1c(cc(cc1C(C)C)C(C)C)c1ccc(F)cc1", "OP(=O)(O)SCCNCCCN", "OC(=O)[C@@H](N)Cc1ccc(O)c(O)c1",    
          "c1ccc(cc1)N1N(C(=O)C(C1=O)CCCC)c1ccccc1", "Nn1nnc2ccccc12")
mols <- parse.smiles(moli)
smarts <- c("[R]", "PCP", "[c]", "[F]", "[I]")
library(rcdk)
fpsmarts <- lapply(mols, get.fingerprint, type='substructure', fp.mode='count',
                    substructure.pattern=smarts)
fpsmarts
str(fpsmarts)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Later edit:

I managed in the end to solve it with a double for loop; not very elegant, but working. I  One may make it better, but this is a working start:

```
lista_fp <- list() # convert the fingerprints (the count values) to a list of lists
for (i in 1:length(fpsmarts)){
  lista_fp[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in 1:length(fpsmarts[[1]]@features)){
    print(i)
    print(j)
    lista_fp[[i]][[j]] <- fpsmarts[[i]]@features[[j]]@count
  }
}

df_fp <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lista_fp), nrow=length(unlist(lista_fp[1]))))
str(df_fp) # 5 obs of 6 variables, as expected
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65088849/6869968 (in short, only atomic types (including list) can be columns of a `data.frame`, you can't have columns of any S4 class)

Comment: Not really. As I edited my question, I managed to get it solved (although probably is not the most elegant solution). Thanks, anyway!

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant solution in this case (an alternative would be to use `lapply` with `slot()` but you will need to nest that two levels deep as well). A third alternative would be to use `outer` on `i` and `j`.